# How to add a class in an HTML cell based on its value

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following loop where I extract values from a query and write a table with it, in the field for the age I need to change the 's class based on the value of the days passed since the date of shipment and today

I already tried with  in CSS like[data-age >180] but I only get errors, and I can't find a case similar to my needs, additionally id like to do it inside the loop instead of an additional piece of code, because it messes up my view

```php
@foreach($shipments as $shipment)
  <tr>
    <td data-title="id">{{$shipment->id}}</td>
    <td class=tracking data-title="tracking">{{$shipment->tracking}}</td>
    <td data-title="PartNumber">{{$shipment->PartNumber}}</td>
    <td data-title="DateShipped">{{$shipment->DateShipped}}</td>
    <td 
      data-title="age" 
      data-age="{{
        (int) floor(
          (time() - strtotime($shipment->DateShipped)) 
          / (60 * 60 * 24)
        )
      }}"
    >{{
      (int) floor(
        (time() - strtotime($shipment->DateShipped)) / (60 * 60 * 24)
      )
    }} days
    </td>

    <td data-title="Qtyorder">{{$shipment->Qtyorder}}</td>
    <td data-title="QtyShipped">{{$shipment->QtyShipped}}</td>
    <td data-title="QtyBckorder">{{$shipment->QtyBckorder}}</td>
    <td data-title="purchaseOrder">{{$shipment->purchaseOrder}}</td>
    <td data-title="OrderNumber">{{$shipment->OrderNumber}}</td>
    <td data-title="paperwork">{{$shipment->paperwork}}</td>
    <td data-title="VMIreceived">{{$shipment->VMIreceived}}</td>
    <td data-title="VMIticketNumber">{{$shipment->VMIticketNumber}}</td>
    <td data-title="VMILRB">{{$shipment->VMILRB}}</td>

    <td>
      <a 
        href="{{ route('shipment.edit',$shipment->id)}}" 
        class="btn btn-primary"
      >
        Edit
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form action="{{ route('shipment.destroy', $shipment->id)}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: can you share the field name and the logic you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but can you please try this:

```
@foreach($shipments as $shipment)
  @php
    $time_passed = $shipment->DateShipped->diffInSeconds(now());
  @endphp

  <tr>
    <td class="{{ time_passed > some_number ? 'class_value_if_true' : 'class_value_if_false' }}">
      {{ $time_passed }}
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i modified your approach a little, but it worked perfectly just changed the variable assignation for php
                    $time_passed = (int) floor((time() - strtotime($shipment->DateShipped)) / (60 * 60 * 24))
                @endphp

Comment: glad to help, smile here.

Answer (score 1):

try a one line if statement

```
{{ $condition ? value if true : value if false }}
```